# REGEXP_SUBSTR help for parsing out parts of a string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in a column that is formatted like this - the parenthesis are used consistently to surround the 2nd and 3rd data pieces, but not the 1st:  [some data (more data) (even more data)]

My table is called 'datasource' the column containing the original data is called 'column'
I am trying to use:

```
Select REGEXP_SUBSTR(column,) as COL1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(column,) as COL2, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(column,) as COL3 
FROM datasource
```

The goal is to get a single row with the following values: COL1 [some data], COL2 [more data], COL3 [even more data] without the surrounding spaces or parenthesis for any of the 3 columns.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to have a parenthesis inside a couple of parentheses? for example `[x ( x(x ) (xxx) ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As data format is constant, pure SUBSTR with INSTR could do the job easily:

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select 'some data (more date)(even more data)' col from dual)
  3  select substr(col, 1, instr(col, '(') - 1) one,
  4    substr(col, instr(col, '(', 1, 1) + 1,
  5                instr(col, ')', 1, 1) - instr(col, '(', 1, 1) - 1) two,
  6    substr(col, instr(col, '(', 1, 2) + 1,
  7                instr(col, ')', 1, 2) - instr(col, '(', 1, 2) - 1) three
  8  from test;

ONE        TWO       THREE
---------- --------- --------------
some data  more date even more data

SQL>
```

Consider modifying data model; as you can see, storing multiple values in a single column is *usually* a bad idea.

Comment: I would if I could. This worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I know you would ... as usual, *we have met the enemy, and they is us*.